# get requests from expressjs and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a simple route in my expressjs app configuration like -

```
app.get('/download/:noteid/:fileid',notes.download);
```

where notes.download is a function with the contents as  -

```
exports.download = function(req,res) {
    console.log("here");
    console.log(req.params.noteid);
    console.log(req.params.fileid);
};
```

now when i open directly in the browser the url -

```
http://localhost:5000/download/5f4815f2-73a9-4621-86ed-b4e302cc49ba/all
```

the i see the correct log in the server
but when i try something like -

```
<a href="/download/5f4815f2-73a9-4621-86ed-b4e302cc49ba/all" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Download</a>
```

and then click on this download button angular takes me to a new page without any template defined for that page and i don't see anything in the logs of my server. so how do i make get requests like the one i make by directly entering in the url by the anchor element.

the route configuration for my angular app is something like this, in case if needed -

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'})
        .when('/admin/users', { templateUrl: '/partials/admin/user-list',
            controller: 'PaginationDemoCtrl'
        })
        .when('/browse/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/browseNotes',
            controller: 'browseNotesCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        })
        .when('/upload/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/uploadNotes',
            controller: 'uploadNotesCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        })
        .when('/profile',{ templateUrl:'/partials/account/mvProfile.jade',
            controller: 'mvProfileCtrl' , resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access the url directly from the address bar it does not go through the routeprovider while when u try to hit the url through the hyperlink(anchor tag) from your webapp , routeprovider checks if there is a path defined for your link.

You can remove the href and use the click event of the anchor tag which calls a function in the controller. This function must call $http module's get method with the url.

or --

add a path for in the routeprovider.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get